# segment the lungs region from X-ray images

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have imported a Kaggle dataset containing a large collection of X-ray images. I aim to detect the lung regions and the outer part of the rib cage, which I want to turn black. Initially, I attempted an approach where it would outline the rib cage, as it is the brightest connected part covering the lungs. However, the dataset images present an issue with labeling L and R text on the side. To mitigate this, I cropped a 10% margin to avoid the texts and then applied my algorithm. Unfortunately, I did not achieve the desired output. Can you help me improve my algorithm or suggest another approach to separate both lungs?  I prefer not to use any pre-trained models.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def crop_xray(image_path, margin_percentage=10):

    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    height, width = image.shape
    margin_x = int(width * margin_percentage / 100)
    margin_y = int(height * margin_percentage / 100)

    cropped_image = image[margin_y:height-margin_y, margin_x:width-margin_x]

    return cropped_image, image

def add_outline(image):
    
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
    
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)
    
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    closed_edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    
    dilated = cv2.dilate(closed_edges, kernel, iterations=3)
    
    dilated = cv2.bitwise_not(dilated)
    
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(dilated, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    outlined_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    
    return outlined_image

xray_image_path = "/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/test/NORMAL/IM-0075-0001.jpeg"

cropped_image, original_image = crop_xray(xray_image_path)

outlined_image = add_outline(cropped_image)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

# Original image
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(original_image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.axis('on')

# Cropped image
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(cropped_image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Cropped Image with 10% Margin')
plt.axis('on')

# Outlined image
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(outlined_image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Outlined Image')
plt.axis('on')

plt.show()
```

output i got
[image]

desired output [somewhat this, can be different but should detect the lungs region]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting close! You may need to adjust the parameters in your outline function to properly catch all of the ribs:

```py
def add_outline(image, kernel_size=(5,5), dilations=3, canny_low=30, canny_high=150):
    
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, kernel_size, 0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, canny_low, canny_high)
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size, np.uint8)
    closed_edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(closed_edges, kernel, iterations=dilations)
    dilated = cv2.bitwise_not(dilated)
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(dilated, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    outlined_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    return outlined_image
```

which I imagine you can figure out with some experimentation.

To create your desired mask, you can mask all pixels to the left and the right of your edges:

```py
def segment_image(image, outlines):
    # image: your input image
    # outlines: just the `mask` from your `add_outline` function
    new_mask = np.zeros_like(image) # assuming your image is grayscaled i.e. no color channel, this should be a 2D array
    for i,(img_row, outline_row) in enumerate(zip(image, outlines)):
        bounds = np.where(outline_row > 0)[0] # find the indices of the edges
        new_mask[i, bounds.min():bounds.max()] = 1 # fill-in the new mask
    return image * new_mask
```

I imagine there is a more vectorized/efficient way to do this, but I think this will get you what you want as a first pass.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I followed your suggestion but didn't achieve the desired result. I tried experimenting with some parameters. Please suggest if i have done anything wrong

https://imgur.com/opt00i3

Comment: Ah, perhaps your masks are not zeros? You may need to change the value in `np.where(...)` to match whatever value your mask actually is.